# Connecting rails with storage services on a coreos cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, service-discovery, coreos

How can I communicate a Rails application with a Postgres DB on a CoreOS cluster? Obviously I can't hardcode storage locations under database.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store and retrieve it from etcd? You can read from etcd over the docker0 bridge: http://coreos.com/docs/distributed-configuration/getting-started-with-etcd/#reading-and-writing-from-inside-a-container